# trigger.io is not working in mac

Tags: ios, trigger.io

HELLO i am facing problem in mac with  trigger.io installing , i have download trigger.io for mac and installing in Applications folder its not working, i use
$ $HOME/Library/Trigger\ Toolkit/forge create command according to https://trigger.io/forge/toolkit/ trigger.io site. but terminal said this directory not found, i also use forge create command but also its not worked,terminal said forge command is not found.Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Run the command as:

`~/Library/Trigger\ Toolkit/forge create`

or

`~/Library/Trigger\ Toolkit/forge`